# How to detect an arrow connected to two shapes in an image: OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: Example]

Hi everyone,

For the last few days I am trying to rediscover all the elements of my image. More specifically, I want to discover the rectangles, the 'ovals', but most importantly also how they are connected to one another.

I am able to discover the rectangles, the ovals and their texts. However, I am having trouble with the arrows. When looking around I find code to discover arrows but is based on the assumption that the arrows are not connected as it counts the corners. Since then I simply don't find a way to identify which shape is connected to another shape.

I have already tried discovering the lines individually, but that returns too many lines fro the other shapes. I have also tried the common online solutions of finding the corners and the lines but is not applicable in my case since the arrows are connected.

I have programmed the code in Python using OpenCV. Does anyone have suggestions of how this could be solved? The image I use to develop my code is attached to this text.

Thanks your help!

Comment: You didn't post your attempt (code). I'm wondering though what's the purpose, maybe there's an alternative way to solve your problem. Analysis of the file which holds the structure of your image components would be easier (e.g. the XML / JSON / whatever it is which holds the data about those relations between entities).

Comment: Well to be fair, I can not post the code due to practical reasons. However the idea is to reconstruct the source file based on an image/ screenshot. I hope that helps?

Comment: Before you detect rectangles and ovals, find the connected components and place each in its own image. Any rectangles and ovals you find in the new images are connected.